# Segmenting customers by email opening days preference?

Tags: sql, pandas, statistics, data-science, analytics

I have a dataset like this that shows for thousands of our customers, their email opens data by day of week. We are trying to segment our customers by certain preferences / patterns that we can find in this data. I am not sure how to approach this mathematically, though.

[image]

The desired result is in the "Segment" column. We're open to doing this in SQL, Python/Pandas, Excel, or whichever tool is relevant.
Really appreciate your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

If your segment's preferences is finding the day that max email opened, you can try this.

Input

```
data = {
    'Customer': ['Matt','Megan', 'John', 'Sally','Sue'],
    'Mon' : [12, 1, 3, 5, 0],
    'Tue' : [0, 2, 1, 6, 1],
    'Wed' : [8, 3, 2, 4, 0],
    'Thu' : [0, 0, 18, 7, 0],
    'Fri' : [3, 2, 0, 7, 2],
    'Sat' : [1, 14, 0, 3, 0],
    'Sun' : [1, 18, 0, 4, 0]
}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Create new segment column

```
df['Segment'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's going to be oversimplistic for me. I don't want the max for each customer, because they might have multiple strong days of preference (like in the example above, Matt clearly prefers Mondays AND Wednesdays). I think it's more of a mathematical question.